# Create Azure NAT server

Tags: linux, azure, nat

For some valid sad reasons, I need a NAT server to translate one private IP, to another private IP that has ExpressRoute access. I'm currently struggling to create a VM that has IP Tables for MASQUERADING. I was wondering if anyone has achieved this on Azure?

Comment: Have you considered using the Azure Firewall? If translation is your only goal, that might serve you better than trying to proxy traffic through a VM.

Comment: @HarrisonGibbs sadly Azure FW requires a public IP, this is something I do not want. This whole set up is internal.

Comment: In addition to Sven Malvik's answer ensure you have IP forwarding enabled on the VM NIC. You can toggle this in the portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will translate `SourceIP` to `TargetIP`. ExpressRoute will send traffic with `TargetIP` as the senders adress. Also, ensure you have IP forwarding enabled on the VM NIC. You can toggle this in the portal.

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

SourceIP=<???>
SourcePort=<???>

TargetIP=<???>
TargetPort=<???>

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --dst $SourceIP -p tcp --dport $SourcePort -j DNAT --to-destination $TargetIP:$TargetPort
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dst $TargetIP --dport $TargetPort -j SNAT --to-source $SourceIP
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT --dst $SourceIP -p tcp --dport $SourcePort -j DNAT --to-destination $TargetIP:$TargetPort

iptables-save
```